OnChange is not called after push new page with UINavigationController
Update: At first, this project need support iOS 14.
I'm working on a mixed project (SwiftUI + UIKit), so I have to use the UINavigationController as the root controller of my window. (or I cannot push any UIKitViewController)
The root is like this:
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
            return
        }
        
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        self.window = window

        //UIKit Navigation as root
        let rootView = AnyView(SwiftUIView1())
        let rootVC = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        let rootNavC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootHubVC)
        window.rootViewController = rootNavC
}

Inside the SwiftUIView1, it has a StateObject
class TestingState: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: TestingState, rhs: TestingState) -> Bool {
        lhs.currentJourneyLevel == lhs.currentJourneyLevel
    }
    
    @Published var currentJourneyLevel: Int {
        willSet {
            debugPrint("##### currentJourneyLevel will be set from \(currentJourneyLevel) to \(newValue)")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        currentJourneyLevel = 1
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView1: View {
    @StateObject private var testingState = TestingState()
    @State var isActived = false {
        didSet {
            debugPrint("##### isActived: \(isActived)")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 30) {
            Button("NextPage") {
                testingState.currentJourneyLevel = 2
            }
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SwiftUIView1(state: testingState),
                isActive: $isActived
            ) { EmptyView() }
        }
        .onChange(of: testingState.currentJourneyLevel) { currentJourneyLevel in
            debugPrint("##### currentJourneyLevel is onChange to: \(currentJourneyLevel)")
            isActived = currentJourneyLevel == 2
        }
        .navigationTitle("SwiftUIView1")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

And inside SwiftUIView2, it has another button to set the currentJourneyLevel back to 1 to pop it to the first view, like this:
struct SwiftUIView2: View {
    private var state: TestingState

    init(state: TestingState) {
        self.state = state
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Button("Back") {
                    state.currentJourneyLevel = 1
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("SwiftUIView2")
        }
    }
}

Once I click the NextPage button, is working as expected, currentJourneyLevel changed to 2 and then the onChange block be called, finally the isActived will be set to true, this is the log:
"##### currentJourneyLevel will be set from 1 to 2"
"##### currentJourneyLevel is onChange to: 2"
"##### isActived: true"

The problem is:
When I'm trying to get back from the second view, the onChange block is not called by the system as expected.
From the log I can see the the value of currentJourneyLevel has been changed correctly, but seems like the system observer is not working, it doesn't call the onChange method as it should be.
"##### currentJourneyLevel will be set from 2 to 1"

However, if I changed to navigation to pure SwiftUI one like this:
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
            return
        }
        
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        self.window = window
        
        //Pure SwiftUI Navigation
        let rootView = SwiftUIContainerView()
        let rootVC = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        window.rootViewController = rootVC
        
        //UIKit Navigation as root
//        let rootView = AnyView(SwiftUIView1())
//        let rootVC = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
//        let rootNavC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
//        window.rootViewController = rootNavC
    }

struct SwiftUIContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            AnyView(SwiftUIView1())
        }
    }
}

Everything will be working smoothly. Click NextPage button:
"##### currentJourneyLevel will be set from 1 to 2"
"##### currentJourneyLevel is onChange to: 2"
"##### isActived: true"

Click Back button:
"##### currentJourneyLevel will be set from 2 to 1"
"##### currentJourneyLevel is onChange to: 1"
"##### isActived: false"

So,
what should I do to make the onChange block working with UIKitNavigationController?
Or if I just made any mistake?
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

I assume you cannot use iOS 16+ APIs?

onChange is for external actions it is not designed for transforming state, best to use computed vars or computed bindings for that.

For view data that isn't using Combine or Delegates you should be using @State not @StateObject. You might need to learn mutating func if are unfamiliar with it.

I'm running into similar issues because onChange is not called on views that have disappeared. UINavigationController by default removes all but the top view controller when pushing SwiftUIView2. Try logging from onDisappear attached to you SwiftUIView1, if it disappears then then onChange will not be handled (in my testing).

@Sweeper I've updated, it's iOS 14

@ShawnThroop onDisappear will always be called whatever I use the SwiftUI NavigationView or UIKit UINavigationController, the different is NavigationView version is working for me.

@Alanc Liu sorry, I've been using the present(_: animated:completion:) which has the same effect as a navigation controller push as when presenting fullScreen (or other modalPresentationStyle that covers full screen). onChange doesn't work while it is offscreen (after onDisappear). My advice would be to move the onChange to outside of views that can disappear, ideally from outside the NavigationStack (though you're using UINavigationController so I'm unsure how to really help you)

When pushing a view/controller onto a NavigationStack/UINavigationController, the views/controllers they cover are removed from the view hierarchy after the animation completes (onDisappear/viewDidDisappear).
This has weird effects if you use .onChange() from inside the stack because the closure is only called while the view/controller is on screen. I've run into this a few times and needed to extract my observing logic to a place that remains visible, ideally outside of the navigation's views/controllers.
Your SwiftUIContainerView has the most potential imo.
struct SwiftUIContainerView: View {
    
    let testingState: TestingState // might need to be a '@State var'
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            SwiftUIView1(state: testingState)
        }
        .onChange(testingState.currentJourneyLevel) { level in
            /// should be called regardless of the visibility of SwiftUIView1
        }
    }
}

Another avenue to consider is the navigationDestination(for:) modifier in coordination with the the path parameter on NavigationStack.
enum Destinations: Hashable {
    case view2
}

If you use an array of Destinations as your path, it could be easier to observe which views have been pushed onto the stack.
    @State private var path = [Destinations]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            SwiftUIView1(state: testingState)
                .navigationDestination(for: Destinations.self) { destination in
                     SwiftUIView2()
                }
        }
        .onChange(path.last == .view2) { isActive in
            /// called when a SwiftUIView2 is pushed/popped
        }
    }

nb: NavigationView is deprecated in favour of NavigationStack.
(Also, all code typed in a browser, not checked by compiler)
